# Making relation one to many on sequelize node js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I've been tried of making relation of one to many on sequelize, i just wanna make the "jadwal" data have data of "dosen".

This's the JadwalModel that have the foreignKey

```
// Main Folder > models > JadwalModel.js

import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
import db from "../config/Database.js";
import Dosen from "./DosenModel.js";

const { DataTypes } = Sequelize;

const Jadwal = db.define('jadwal', {
    id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
    id_dosen: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    room: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    date: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true
});

// Dosen.hasMany(Jadwal, { foreignKey: 'id_dosen' });
// Jadwal.belongsTo(Dosen, { foreignKey: 'id_dosen' }); // This return ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Dosen' before initialization

export default Jadwal;
```

This's the Dosen model that the primaryKey/ ReferenceKey

```
// Main Folder > models > DosenModel.js

import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
import db from '../config/Database.js';
import Jadwal from "./JadwalModel.js";

const { DataTypes } = Sequelize;

const Dosen = db.define('dosen', {
    id_dosen: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    id_matkul: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    id_user: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    nip: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    refresh_token: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true
});

// Dosen.hasMany(Jadwal, { foreignKey: 'id_dosen' });
// Jadwal.belongsTo(Dosen, { foreignKey: 'id_dosen' });

export default Dosen;
```

This's the jadwal controller the file to get the data

```
// Main Folder > controllers > Jadwal.js

import Dosen from '../models/DosenModel.js';
import Jadwal from '../models/JadwalModel.js';

export const getJadwals = async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const jadwal = await Jadwal.findAll({
            attributes: ['id', 'id_dosen', 'room', 'date']
        }, {
            include: [{ model: Dosen }]
        });
        res.status(200).json(jadwal);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

And this's the example result

```
// Result

[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "id_dosen": 1,
    "room": "Ruang TR 2",
    "date": "2022-05-26T10:00:00.000Z"
  }
]

// The result that i want is
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "dosen": {
            "name" : "dosenName"
    },
    "room": "Ruang TR 2",
    "date": "2022-05-26T10:00:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That wasn't error, i just forgot because i only fetch several field not all so i decide to delete the attributes and get the data relation

```
attributes: ['id', 'id_dosen', 'ruangan', 'tanggal']
```